# Website van wordpress omzetten naar Magmento?

Tags: wordpress

Wij lopen al een langere tijd tegen een aantal problemen aan met onze website [AED](https://www.aedmaster.nl/)master. Het is namelijk zo dat wij de website graag verder willen upgraden, zodat deze sneller wordt. Onze huidige website is in Wordpress gebouwd en de webbouwer geeft aan at hij op zoek gaat naar een andere plugin. Echter heb ik het idee dat al die plugins niet bijdragen aan een snellere site.

Mijn vraag is of dit ook met een website van Magmento geldt en of het eennvoudig is om een wordpress site om te zetten naar een magmento site?

Ik hoop dat er iemand id die mij verder kan helpen.

Comment: Beste AEDMaster, dit forum is in het Engels. Vragen in het Nederlands zullen weinig tot geen antwoord ontvangen. De beste reacties komen op concrete, technische vragen.
Voor een Nederlandstalig forum verwijs ik je graag naar https://community.magento.com/t5/Dutch/bd-p/netherlands

Answer (score 0):

Een webshop met WordPress en WooCommerce is prima te optimaliseren voor snelheid, daar is Magento niet specifiek voor nodig. Maak zo min mogelijk gebruik van plugins en maak vooral gebruik van caching.

Hier 5 handige tips om je website sneller te maken:
https://www.b2design.nl/blog/geef-een-snelheidsboost-aan-je-wordpress-website

Succes!